# Sql create new rows and update associated values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with poorly designed table in oracle. Table structure below.

```
| Id| Dtransaction |Hotel|
| --|-----         | ----|
| 1 | 100          |Hotel1|
| 2 |2000          |Hotel2|
| 3 |-100          |Hotel2|
| 4 | 500          |Hotel3|
| 5 | 1000         |Hotel5|
| 6 |500           |Hotel12.Hotel1|
| 7 |700           | Hotel5|
```

I have to create a query which will return sum of transactions, group by Hotel. But if Hotel Name contains "." than have to create two rows, first part of the string will contain negative transaction and second part will be positive transaction. E.g 500 | Hotel1.Hotel2| should be divided into two rows

```
| Id| Dtransaction |Hotel|
| 1 | 500          |Hotel1|
| 2 | -500         |Hotel12|
```

Managed to create following query

```
  Select Hotel, sum(Dtransaction) from 
  HotelTransaction
  group by Hotel
```

But i am unable break Hotel that contain comma seperated hotel name and distribute the transaction values based on position in string

Tried my best to explain the problem.

Comment: Which version of Oracle do you have?

Comment: Oracle Version 19c

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Oracle supports `APPLY`/`LATERAL` we can conditionally add a row using that.

```sql
SELECT calc.Hotel, SUM(calc.Dtransaction)
from HotelTransaction h
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN h.Hotel LIKE '%.%' THEN
            SUBSTR(h.Hotel, INSTR(h.Hotel, '.') + 1)
        ELSE h.Hotel
        END AS Hotel,
        h.Dtransaction
    FROM dual    -- just generate a single row on the fly
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SUBSTR(h.Hotel, 1, INSTR(h.Hotel, '.') - 1),
        -h.Dtransaction
    FROM dual
    WHERE h.Hotel LIKE '%.%'    --conditionally generate another row
) calc
GROUP BY calc.Hotel;
```

Comment: You have several syntax errors and one logical error in this solution. Syntax: table and subquery aliases can't be preceded by the keyword `AS` (in Oracle SQL); there is no comma before `cross apply`. Logical error: the hotel names without a dot must be grouped together with the SECOND hotel names in the rows that have two hotel names separated by dot (and must appear with the `dtransaction` value); the only ones that are "separate" are the FIRST part of compound names, with `-dtransaction` contributed to the sum. Read the problem description again and you will understand.

Comment: Hum think it's all fixed now?

Comment: Yep, it seems so. Note about the comma: new in Oracle 12.1, we were able to use the `lateral` and the `cross apply` clauses. `lateral` is similar to the old, Oracle notation for joins, including the comma in the `from` clause (instead of the keyword `join`). `cross apply` is the equivalent of the ANSI syntax for joins (no comma in the `from` clause).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You want the "last" part of the name after the `'.'` to be positive and the first part (if any) to be negative.  One method is:

```
select hotel, sum(Dtransaction)
from ((select regexp_substr(hotel, '[^.]+$') as hotel, Dtransaction
       from HotelTransaction
      ) union all
      (select regexp_substr(hotel, '^[^.]+'), -Dtransaction
       from HotelTransaction
       where hotel like '%.%'
      )
     ) h
group by hotel;
```

Comment: Why a double scan of the table, you can do this in one scan?

Answer (score 0):

All in a single pass, using a cross join to a very small "helper" table created on the fly, and basic aggregation:

```
create table hoteltransaction (id, dtransaction, hotel) as
  select 1,  100, 'Hotel1'         from dual union all
  select 2, 2000, 'Hotel2'         from dual union all
  select 3, -100, 'Hotel2'         from dual union all
  select 4,  500, 'Hotel3'         from dual union all
  select 5, 1000, 'Hotel5'         from dual union all
  select 6,  500, 'Hotel12.Hotel1' from dual union all
  select 7,  700, 'Hotel5'         from dual
;

select case q.n when 1 then substr(h.hotel, 1, instr(h.hotel, '.') - 1)
                       else substr(h.hotel, instr(h.hotel, '.') + 1) end 
       as hotel
     , sum(case q.n when 1 then -h.dtransaction else h.dtransaction end)
       as dtransaction
from   hoteltransaction h
         inner join 
       (select level as n from dual connect by level <= 2) q
         on q.n = 2 or instr(h.hotel, '.') > 0
group  by case q.n when 1 then substr(h.hotel, 1, instr(h.hotel, '.') - 1)
                          else substr(h.hotel, instr(h.hotel, '.') + 1) end
;

HOTEL          DTRANSACTION
-------------- ------------
Hotel1                  600
Hotel3                  500
Hotel2                 1900
Hotel12                -500
Hotel5                 1700
```

Unfortunately SQL (at least the Oracle dialect) doesn't allow us to use the name "hotel" for the `case` expression in `group by` - we must write exactly the same thing in both places (or else use a subquery - outer query structure), but the computation is, in fact, performed only once. The query doesn't look "neat", but performance is not affected since the computation is only done once and the result is used in both places.

Comment on your data model: it is doubly bad, since it uses free-form description of hotels, instead of hotel id's. Do you have any authority to get the model changed? To illustrate the problem - your sample data had an errant space before "Hotel5" in your sample inputs (last row). I assumed it's a typo, but what if the real-life data actually contains such errant spaces? Now you must write all your queries to handle such bad data - assuming you even know that you have bad data to begin with. This should be a good argument for your "bosses" to let you make the needed changes.

Comment: unfortunately don't have authority to change data model due to legacy issues.